# Tax Reporting for Teen Freelancer using PayPal and Outsourcing Work: Necessary Steps?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, tax-deduction, paypal, minor

I have a 16-year-old doing some freelancing as a side gig. I'm pretty certain that the PayPal income does not meet the $20k/200 threshold. There has not been any 1099 forms from PayPal. Should any actions be taken?

The freelancing "work" is also actually 1. finding clients and 2. finding ghostwriters/designers to do work assigned by the clients. So, how to write and deduct #2 off, if possible?

Answer (score 3):

Whether or not there's any form 1099 is irrelevant, taxable income is not defined by a form.

#2 is a business deduction. If you're subcontracting some work to someone else you get their details through form W8/W9 as appropriate, report on 1099 as appropriate and deduct it as an expense in the appropriate category of your [schedule C](https://www.irs.gov/forms-pubs/about-schedule-c-form-1040). For example, [line 11](https://www.irs.gov/instructions/i1040sc#en_US_2022_publink24329wd0e1259). [Check instructions](https://www.irs.gov/instructions/i1040sc) to see if that's appropriate to your use case.